# Why was my question closed? No comments, suggestions, anything

Tags: discussion

I did my search within suggested existing questions and answers but haven't found what I am looking for.

So I created new [question - any multiuser trip planner](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/any-multiuser-trip-planner-application)...

I understand that someone has the feeling that .... Could you please make comments so I 'improve' (my questions)? Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Based on recent discussion among moderators and in the post: [Double standards on web app recommendation questions?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/double-standards-on-web-app-recommendation-questions), we have decided to move to close these questions, if the user does not show any effort in finding alternatives on their own.

> What's good is when a question comes through where the user has obviously tried their hand at something, anything, and now needs further assistance or a brand new set of eyes in order to push them through the gates.

Instead of asking a list of any and every planner application, we rather you ask about finding out how to do a certain task within a planner application (that you have researched on your own) and if this task is not possible in X app we can recommend a Y app (or browser extension) that does.

*What can you do to improve your question?*

- Research a bit on what planner applications you have found out in the wild, see what works and what does not
- When you have found a few, at this point you have either answered your question or see a limitation that needs to be addressed
- Edit your question with your research and the current limitation

Once this is done and the community considers that it shows effort it will be reopened.