# Where should I ask about what helpdesk software to use?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a certain type of web app but I found that is considered off-topic here.

Which Stack Exchange site would be appropriate?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that this is in response to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24050/helpdesk-with-user-roles) that has been closed.

In short, there isn't anywhere on Stack Exchange that this question would be appropriate as it is essentially a recommendation/shopping question.

There has already been a [discussion on meta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/double-standards-on-web-app-recommendation-questions/1003#1003) about these types of questions.

If your question was about a specific Web Application relating to a specific problem that you have encountered then you might have a bit more luck. If you just want a list of recommendations then this isn't the place.

Off the top of my head, you could try using http://alternativeto.net/ which might provide you with a list of suitable Applications.

Comment: We should just redirect anyone trying to use [webapp-rec] to Alternative.To and other such directories.

Answer (score 2):

Recommendation requests for web *applications* are considered on-topic for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). Note that recommendations for web *sites* are not accepted there; the web tool you ask for needs to "act like an application". <sup>[1](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/219/156)</sup>