# I wonder if you could please reopen "How can I find a cuddle friend online?"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Earlier this year, ChrisF voted to close ["How can I find a cuddle friend online?"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/29018/how-can-i-find-a-cuddle-friend-online/54435), claiming that I haven't [specified what I've tried already](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1003). But, in fact, I indeed specified what I've tried already — in the self-answers I posted. I wonder if, therefore, it could please be reopened?

Comment: Note to self: Software Recommendations didn't accept the question either. Izzy, one of their moderators, [wrote](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/22961/how-can-i-find-a-cuddle-friend-online): "The question is off-topic here, and so are the answers: This site is about recommending software for specific needs – not any kind of web resources or websites."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The guidelines for the site's scope have not changed in the intervening time.  Please see [Make all recommendation questions out of scope and off topic, regardless of research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2595/make-all-recommendation-questions-out-of-scope-and-off-topic-regardless-of-rese) as to why questions asking to recommend a website are off-topic, regardless of whether you included which sites you have tried already.

As was also mentioned in comments on the original question, it appears that the link you have provided in the question is promoting a blog post.  Stack Exchange has a policy against this type of [self-promotion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

As such, the question will not be reopened.

Comment: I would say that if the community wanted it re-opened it would have been by now. That really isn't the kind of question we want here.

Comment: It's true that my original question did contain a link to an article by a woman in Australia. This was neither promotion nor self-promotion. I have never met this woman or communicated with her. I just think it's a useful article for those who are interested in having a cuddle friend.

Comment: Still, thank you for explaining why my original question was deleted.